# How do I 'decorate' a complex C# class to properly deserialize from a rest endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml-parsing, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

When using a rest endpoint, I can test it with RestClient and get well-formed XML back. I can copy and paste the XML into a POCO using VS2012's 'Paste XML as Classes' feature.

Then I try to use Web API to hit the same endpoint and convert the XML into my POCO but usually never works right out of the box.

Usually, for the simpler classes, I can decorate members with a variety of annotations and get it working. Why is this? Why won't the original generated class work with Web API?

[XmlElement("dateAdded")]
[DataMember]

What I am finding is that the more complex XML types returned from the endpoint are nearly impossible to properly deserialize as I don't know how to decorate the class. Where can I find a guide that shows me how to do this?

thanks in advance -

Comment: Can you give an example of a "more complex XML type"?  Is it a nested node or something else?

Comment: Arrays of objects for example...

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a sample snippet of the XML?  Without looking at the actual XML, it's hard to tell exactly why it is not working...

One thing to try though is to set the Web API's `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` to use the `XmlSerializer` instead of the default `DataContractSerializer`.

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have opened up a new question with some details inside. Thanks all for viewing and helping so far!

[Using 'Paste XML as Classes' to deserialize a Web API rest response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237665/using-paste-xml-as-classes-to-deserialize-a-web-api-rest-response-beginner)