# Using 'Paste XML as Classes' to deserialize a Web API rest response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, deserialization

I am having trouble using the 'Paste XML as Classes' feature in VS2012 to properly deserialize XML results from a Rest call using Web API.

The XML response from the call looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SCResponse>
    <AccountId>86</AccountId>
    <Administrator>false</Administrator>
    <Email>6z@z.com</Email>
    <FirstName>6z@z.com</FirstName>
    <Label>false</Label>
    <LastName>6z@z.com</LastName>
    <link href="https://cnn.com" rel="news" title="News"/>
</SCResponse>
```

I copied this XML and used the handy new feature to paste this XML as classes:

```
namespace Models.account.response
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SCResponse")] // I added this so I could name the object Account
    [DataContract(Name = "SCResponse", Namespace = "")] // I added this as the namespace was causing me problems
    public partial class Account
    {
        public byte AccountId { get; set; }

        public bool Administrator { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public bool Label { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("link")]
        public SCResponseLink[] Link { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class SCResponseLink
    {
        private string hrefField;

        private string relField;

        private string titleField;

        [XmlAttribute)]
        public string href { get; set; }

        XmlAttribute]
        public string rel { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string title { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I call the REST endpoint like so:

```
string path = String.Format("account/{0}", id);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(path).Result;  // Blocking call!
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Parse the response body. Blocking!
    account = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Models.account.response.Account>().Result;
}
```

and examine the fields of the Account object -- all are null or defaulting to initialized values.

In my Global.asax.cs Application_Start method, I am registering the XML Serializer:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Comment: Do you need the [DataMember] attributes added to each property when using [DataContract]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way to handle this might be to use the [RestSharp library](http://restsharp.org/), which will do all of the deserialization for you. This will simplify your calls, and you won't need the XML attributes on your model.

Take a look here for a good example of doing aync calls with RestSharp:

[How should I implement ExecuteAsync with RestSharp on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153749/how-should-i-implement-executeasync-with-restsharp-on-windows-phone-7)

Hopefully this helps.